# The requested resource is not available error: Rest Jersey (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I have been trying to work on Rest application using jersey,tomcat and eclipse but I am getting a 404 error (The requested resource is not available.) I did go through all the similar errors but I haven't been able to fix this.

this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.kushal.rest.testRest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I cross checked the servlet name and it is matching. 
I tried with jdk 1.7 and tomcat 7 and also with jdk 1.8 and tomcat 8 and different version of jersey the latest I tried was 2.25.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.kushal.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>testRest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testRest</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>testRest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.25</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

this is my resource.java file

```
package org.kushal.rest.testRest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

http://localhost:8080/testRest/myresource
http://localhost:8080/testRest
kindly let me know what I am doing wrong since I am stuck from past 3 days.

```
here are the logs:

Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:messenger' did not find a matching property.
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 9 2016 08:48:39 UTC
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.39.0
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-b15
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\kushaldileep\New_Rest\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Courses\273\apache-tomcat-8.0.39
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\kushaldileep\New_Rest\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Courses\273\apache-tomcat-8.0.39
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\kushaldileep\New_Rest\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Courses\273\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\endorsed
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Users\kushaldileep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\kushaldileep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\kushaldileep\Anaconda2;C:\Users\kushaldileep\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\kushaldileep\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Users\kushaldileep\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\kushaldileep\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Courses\273\Enide-2015-7-windows-x64-20150706\eclipse;;.
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1636 ms
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:04 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [101] milliseconds.
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 29, 2017 5:11:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 901 ms
```

Comment: `testRest/webapi/myresource`. Looks the web.xml url-pattern. That is part of the url.

Comment: Do you have any logging? For tomcat, for example, it would be useful to check catalina.out and localhost_access log with the application deployed to it.

Comment: @peeskillet I did try this http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/myresource still shows the same.

Comment: @SergeiSirik: I just created a new Maven project in a new workspace to check again I have attached the logs in the question

Comment: Try to access localhost:8080/testRest/webapi/myresource URL

Comment: @VikasSachdeva I tried but that shows the same error

Comment: How exactly are you deploying it? Is it through the IDE or are you adding the war to the server manually? If the former, maybe it's a problem with deploying through the IDE. I've seen people have problem trying use a Maven project and just clicking Run in Eclipse. Not sure what the problem is because I don't really use Eclispe

Comment: You don't have any mention of your package is being deployed to the server in the log. Just build the package and put it under `webapps` directory in the tomcat and check `catalina.out` again, you should see that the package `testRest.war` or whatever name your war has is deployed or some error during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to change how is created your `pom.xml`, first I start using your pom.xml but it gives me the same error.

Not try this, the pom.xml was created based on the maven repositories and dependencies that I can detect as the mandatory for your project.  This is the step by step (in this case I'm using Eclipse Oxygen, Tomcat 9, java 8)

1. Open Eclipse
2. File > New > Dynamic Web Project
   2.1  Project name: `my-jersey-project`
3. Click on finish
4. Right click on `my-jersey-project` > Configure >  **Convert to Maven** Project
   4.1  Group id: `org.jersey.demo.project` 
   4.2  Click on finish
5. Open pom.xml after `</build>` section add this dependencies

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

6. Expand `my-jersey-project` project and right click over *Deployment Descriptor: my-jersey-project*  >  select **Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub**
7. Open `web.xml` that is just created from previous step,

It is the content of web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>my-jersey-project</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jersey.demo.project</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

8. Go to `src` folder, and create a new package called `org.jersey.demo.project`
9. In `org.jersey.demo.project` create a new java class called `Hello`

it is the content of `Hello` class

```
package org.jersey.demo.project;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String output = "Hello Jersey this is the param value: " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

}
```

**This step is very important**

10. Right click over `my-jersey-project` > **Maven** > **Update Project** , make sure that `my-jersey-project` is selected > click ok and please wait a moment until maven dependencies are properly loaded to your project.
11. Right click over `my-jersey-project` > run as > Run on server >select tomcat server (assuming that the tomcat server is already configured on your eclipse) > click on finish
12. Finally try your rest service: `http://localhost:8080/my-jersey-project/rest/hello/hijersey`
13. It is the output that I get from test: *Hello Jersey this is the param value: hijersey*

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much for that Daniel. However I was getting this error:org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer ClassNotFoundException

so i did the following settings:project Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries -> Gradle Dependencies -> Finish.

Comment: That being said I was just curious to know. Why normal creation of the maven project wasn't working ??

Comment: Actually I got the `ClassNotFoundException` the fist time that I change the `pom.xml` I noticed that eclipse didn't finish the task Building Workspace, then I restart eclipse and right click project > maven > update project, and then when I saw that Building Workspace task was finished then I Run as Server and got worked.  Sometimes when that happens to me I also delete my entire `.m2` repo and start again, I don't know the root cause of that behavior with Eclipse maybe is my computer.

Comment: by the way did it work on your pc? I mean the jersey rest service, did you get success with the rest invocation?

Comment: Yes I worked on my pc I did get success with the invocation and created more resources as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just built your package and copied the war file to tomcat `webapps` directory, and this endpoint `localhost:8080/testRest/webapi/myresource` works. Here is catalina.out snippet regarding `testRest.war` deployment:

```
30-Aug-2017 12:21:52.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/ssiryk/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.020 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.052 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.056 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8000"]
30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.056 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.057 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.310 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.310 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.312 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.313 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 883 ms
30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.342 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.342 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
**30-Aug-2017 12:21:53.368 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/testRest.war
30-Aug-2017 12:21:54.119 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
30-Aug-2017 12:21:54.959 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/testRest.war has finished in 1,590 ms**
30-Aug-2017 12:21:54.960 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/docs
30-Aug-2017 12:21:54.972 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/docs has finished in 12 ms
```

I marked the lines regarding `testRest.war` deployment.
Hope this helps!